# Testing a React component that modifies an external element

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a React component that, when clicked, updates the style of an HTML element that lives outside of it. Here's what that method looks like:

```
_hideContent() {
  let content = document.getElementById("container");
  content.style.top = 100vh;
  ...
}
```

When I try to test it using `TestUtils.simulate.click()`, I get an error due to the external HTML element not being found. The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at FilterButtonMobile._hideContent (public/js/FilterButtonMobile/components/FilterButtonMobile.react.jsx:45:14)
    ...
```

How can I test this component?

Comment: possible without _#_ just simple _container_ ... when you are trying to *getElementById('container')*

Comment: That was actually just a mistake when I typed it in here (I've edited to correct it). It's correct in the actual code so that's not the problem. It's working fine in the browser, just not in the tests.